# Error when trying to run a Qt app on android

Tags: android, qt

I'm trying to run an app I made in Qt to a Samsung Galaxy Gio. When it tries to run it sends me this:

> I/ApplicationPackageManager( 1268): cscCountry is not German : TMM.

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: Already solved it, I was missing some libraries